# Change View using EmptyView fullScreenCover not working in iOS 15

Tags: swiftui

Days ago, I was using:

```
class SplashViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isActive: Bool = false
    @Published var isMantinance: Bool = false
    @Published var hasPreviousLogIn:Bool = false
}


struct SplashView: View {
@ObservedObject var model = SplashViewModel()

func verifyMantinance() {
   model.isActive = true
}

var body: some View {
        
        Color.init(hex: "#FFFFFF")
            .overlay(
            
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                
                EmptyView().fullScreenCover(isPresented: $model.isActive)
                      { QueryView() }

                GeometryReader { gp in
                    ZStack {
                        
                        Image("logo")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 35, leading: 20, bottom: 10, trailing: 20))
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75)
                            .position(x: gp.size.width / 2, y: gp.size.height / 2)
                            
                            .onAppear {
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
                                    self.verify()
                                }
                            }
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            
            ).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        
    }
}
```

It's was working properly with iOS 14, once I updated my device to iOS 15, the redirection with `EmptyView().fullScreenCover` is not working anymore. Nothing happens, no error, no warning, nothing related to this process.

Someone have an idea about how I can make it work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is easily fixed, just "attach"

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $model.isActive){ QueryView() }
```

to the VStack.
There is no need for the `EmptyView`

Comment: this doesnt work when you have multiple